# MVC How to pass in a relational ID from a model into a partial view with a different model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I want to add a create function to my page, it has a buildings page and a rooms page however depending on which building is chosen rooms corresponding to its ID are shown. I have that completed but I wanted to add a create function to add more rooms when in a specific building. I have all the required code for creating/inserting in a partial view but I need to pass in relational value without having to put it in myself. Similar to this action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", **new { id=item.Id }**)
```

Here is my room page:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h3>Rooms in: @Model.buildingName</h3>
<ol class="round">

<li class="one">
    <h5>Please begin creating your network structure:</h5> <button id="modal-opener">Add a new room</button>

</li>
<li class="two">

</li>
</ol>
@*rooms that are specific to a building are shown here*@
@Html.Partial("rooms", Model.roomId)

<div id="Modal" title="room Details">
@Html.Partial("roomForm", new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo())
</div>
```

my displayed rooms partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo>

<div class="Container">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{<div class="Box">
    <div>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.roomName</h4>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.roomNumber</h4>
        <p>@item.roomDesc1</p>
        <p>@item.roomDesc2</p>
        <p>@item.roomDesc3</p>
    </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

my roomForm partial view:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("roomForm", "Home"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>roomInfo</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.roomNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.roomNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.roomNumber)
    </div>
    ....
    //Here I would like the building Id to be passed automatically from the buildingInfo model which is being called in the rooms view
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.buildingId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.buildingId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingId)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

This is the model that I'm using to store data with:

```
public class buildingInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int buildingNumber { get; set; }
    public String buildingName { get; set; }
    public String buildingDesc1 { get; set; }
    public String buildingDesc2 { get; set; }
    public String buildingDesc3 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<roomInfo> roomId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the roomInfo model:

```
public class roomInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    public String roomName { get; set; }
    public String roomDesc1 { get; set; }
    public String roomDesc2 { get; set; }
    public String roomDesc3 { get; set; }
    public int buildingId { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<rackInfo> rackId { get; set; }
}
```

If anymore information is needed please ask and I will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking to a solution using `ViewDataDictionary` but I just realised you can pass the value through the constructor of your object.
So you can try this:

```
@Html.Partial("roomForm",new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo { buildingId=Model.Id })
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Ahh I see. I wasn't aware you could do that. I had to change it however as I was getting an error. saying that I could not explicitly convert the ICollection type. I substituted A Viewbag containing the building ID and it took it.

Comment: I'm still having an issue where the buildingId isn't being saved properly with the ICollection type. Here is the error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo>' to 'int'

Comment: Your right in using { buildingId=Model.roomId } //roomId is the ICollection type. But it won't take.

Comment: I tried @Html.Partial("roomForm", new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo { Model.roomId = ViewBag.buildId}) but the error that came back is Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Don't you have `Model.buildingId`? I haven't written ` { buildingId=Model.roomId }`

Comment: yes but its Model.Id. I posted my model up at the top.

Comment: buildingNumber is for the user to see, I'm using Id as the key.

Comment: did you mean { buildingId=Model.Id } or { Model.Id = Model.roomId }, I tried both, but not working, We need to some how pass the buildingId into Model.roomId. I don't think it will work in that line as it is asking for an IEnumerable which there is non in the form.

Comment: Please could you paste the roomInfo model?

Comment: I added it at the top.

Comment: So even by intellisense can't you access to properties?

Comment: yes I can but because Model.roomId requires an IEnumerable to be in the partial view, it won't allow it in. here is the error: Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: But roominfo model doesn't have a collection in, it seems you attempt the first partial, I meant {buildingId=ModeliD}, with the @model TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo

Comment: I see what you mean now, I was getting an error because of @using (Html.BeginForm("roomForm", "Home")), It was redirecting me to a page that doesn't exist, such a stupid mistake. And yes buildingId = Modal.Id works, it is auto filled in the form straight away. but for some reason its not saving.

Comment: Glad it passes. For saving you should ask another question as this one is answered or just update by showing the code of the saving action

Comment: I changed it to @using (Html.BeginForm("roomForm")). Its saving now but not to posting the result back onto the page. I looked in the Database and the column buildingInfo_Id(I presume is the roomId collection) remains empty. I put in the correct Id there and it appeared on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the other Question. But I prefer to answer here maybe it will solve the second problem. Because there are many solutions. But I think maybe the first I gave doesn't allow you to populate this value for some reason.

Could you try this:using a overload of `Html.Partial()` method and passing a `ViewDataDictionary` with the value you want.
You need to change this line:

```
@Html.Partial("roomForm", new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo())
```

To:

```
@Html.Partial("roomForm", new TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo(), new ViewDataDictionary { {"buildingId", Model.buildingId} } )
```

And in your partial view, you can retrieve it like this:

```
 @model TerminalHost.Models.roomInfo

 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  }
 @{
   int buildingId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["buildingId"]);
  }
 ........

 <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.buildingId,new {@Value=buildingId })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingId)
</div>
```

I hope by doing in this way it will solve the second problem.

Comment: I changed Model.buildingId to Model.Id, it worked the same way the as theprevious solution. I see how this works but however it unfortunately hasn't fixed the second problem. The ICollection roomId(buildingInfo_Id in the database) remains unchanged. Is there another way to perform the relations without using the ICollection as as its causing the bug or whatever is the problem.